# Changes made in LibreOffice impression master slides are not seen in presentation

Tags: libreoffice

I need presentation frequently for my teaching, when I want to make changes presentation wide using master view it is not shown in presentation and I need to do it manually for each slides

Answer (score 2):

Some things seem to work when changing an attribute on the master slide.  For example, specifying a different background, is carried out across all slides.  The difficulty I have is changing the font.  I can change this on the master slide but the new setting isn't carried over to any of the presentation slides.  A workaround seems to be to select the text on one of the slides in the actual presentation, then navigate to Format - Styles and Formatting - Right click on the highlighted style and select Modify.  Change the Font and/or Font Effects and press OK.  The new font should now be displayed on all slides.

Comment: Thanks, This is working for fonts, background and slide transition but if you add custom animation it is not working